# Determing Big Oh Of Given Data

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to determine the big O time complexity of the following
[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sStmD.png) where the first column is the input size, and the second column is the execution time in seconds. Where possible, I should determine the exponent of the dominant term and provide an estimate for the coefficient on the dominant term.

---

I made the following
[graph of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRRVJ.png) and a [log/log graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onTqC.png) to try and figure it out. At first I thought it might have been 1/n or something along those lines but as n gets quite large, the execution time increases again instead of asymptotically approaching a value.

The log graph having such a distinct pattern leads me to believe that the answer will lie there but I'm stuck as to where to go from here. Any help would be great.

Comment: I am not sure if you can say that it seems like the time converges. If that is so, it would be O(1) as you are allowed to ignore finite many n from 1 to some k.

Comment: I think just skip first 200 values and then map it to function; Algorithm may have some optimization for smaller data sets is all i can guess but you can safely skip it to there and map it to function;